# Is it possible to use a <caption> tag in a form?

Tags: html, forms

Can I use the `<caption>` tag inside a form ? If not, why not?

Example:

```
<form>
<caption>description</caption>
<label>name:</label>
<input />
</form>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you actually *tried* it first?

**Answer: no.** (Well, you *can*, but it would break standards).

The [`<caption>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-CAPTION) element is used to caption a *table*, not a *form*.

**Alternative solution:**

If you *really* want to caption forms, simply add a valid element that can be styled with CSS to it, like so:

```
<form>
    <div class="caption">This is my form caption</div>
    <input .../>
</form>
```

**Another approach**, that would probably be more semantically correct, would be to use a [`<fieldset>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FIELDSET) to group your form:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>This is my form caption</legend>
    <form>
        <input .../>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @Anas, it would be a problem in *every* browser, really. Don't use captions inside forms.

Comment: This is quite old but ran across this and the syntax should be for standards conformity. Only doing this because it was the accepted answer.
    <form>
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <fieldset><label></label>`<input .../></fieldset>
      </form>

Comment: I am from China, and I am not quite familiar with English vocabulary, my question is why use `legend` not `caption` word

Comment: @0oneo -- simply stated: because that's the way HTML is defined. You should always prefer valid HTML over invalid HTML, if you want browsers to represented it in expected ways.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) tag, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `caption` element pertains specifically to tables. One may argue it's a strange case of omission on part of whoever helped make HTML what it is today, but be it as it may, it cannot be used with forms. Furthermore, there are semantical implications of trying to use `caption` for a form, since it captions tables and not forms.

The idiomatic way to "caption" or "head" content in HTML, including announcing forms and form content, is to use the heading tags `h1`, `h2` etc. These are generic with regard to what they help announce and you may therefore well precede or nest these within a `form` element.

In your case you would then have:

```html
<form>
<h1>description</h1>
<label>name:</label>
<input />
</form>
```

or you could also put the heading element directly preceding the `form` element:

```html
<h1>description</h1>
<form>
<label>name:</label>
<input />
</form>
```

I think the former is more semantically applicable, but sometimes certain factors like abilities of CSS, will necessitate use of the latter. Either should be valid, regardless.